# Why is allolactose the LacI inducer?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, molecular-evolution

For what reason(s) is allolactose, instead of lactose, the "natural" inducer of *lac* operon repressor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When lactose is present in a cell, some of it is enzymatically converted by $\beta$-galactosidase from the $\beta(1,4)$ linkage (typical of lactose) to the $\beta(1,6)$ glycosidic linkage (becoming allolactose). Allolactose and other analogues can then bind LacI to induce the appropriate conformational change and unbind the *lac* operator (one such [review](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=23011886) here).

Why does allolactose act as a signal of lactose presence instead of just lactose? From the perspective of the lac operon, there is no operational difference between lactose and allolactose -- either way one molecule binds LacI and cannot be metabolized while bound. The full paradox is explained by [Edgel](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=3072716) and summarized by well-known biochemistry textbook author and scientist, Larry Moran, on his [personal blog](http://sandwalk.blogspot.ca/2008/10/lactose-paradox.html). The short version is that neither allolactose nor lactose are the intended substrates for $\beta$-gal and instead a different sugar entirely is the "natural" inducer and substrate.

1. [Juers DH, Matthews BW, Huber RE. LacZ β-galactosidase: structure and function of an enzyme of historical and molecular biological importance. Protein Sci. 2012 1792-807.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=23011886)
2. [Egel R. The 'lac' operon: an irrelevant paradox? Trends Genet. 1988 Feb;4(2):31.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=3072716)